# Weighting unbalanced object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, weight

Hopefully my question is not out of order in this site.

I am trying to weigh an object that is too wide/long for my weight scale. If just put it on top of it it tips over.

So my solution is to place my hand on the 'short side' to prevent it from tipping over. Assuming I am not pushing (just holding my hand as an 'stopper'), does that change the weight the weight scale measures? why/why not?. I guess if I push the measured weight would increase (not sure either).

details: I am trying to weigh a planter to know if it is safe to put in the balcony.

[image]

Comment: What does the scale look like? Is it a normal bathroom scale or what? There are other ways to get an accurate read, and using your finger may not give you one as accurate.

Comment: Can you put it on two scales and add the weights?

Comment: Normal bathroom scale. The two scales ideas might work out. I'll try it out.

Comment: Two bathroom scales without hands match (~3% error) one bathroom scale with the hand. I guess it is good enough for my application - I would love to know the theory behind it. Thanks guys @josephh and mmesser314.

Comment: It's actually very simple. You have two scales which both must support the weight of the object, so the total $W_T=W_1+W_2$ is the sum of each individual reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying some kind of force with your hand and that affects the scale.

Let us figure out what the scale will read based on the geometry of the problem

[image: fig1]

We balance the forces and torques about the pivot

$$\begin{aligned}
 N - W - F &= 0 \\
 (a/2) F - (a/2-x) N & = 0 \\
\end{aligned}$$

Where $W$ is the weight of the object, $N$ is the scale measurement and $F$ is the force you push down to keep the object level.

The solution of the above is

$$ \begin{aligned}
F &= \left( \frac{a}{2 x}-1 \right) W \\
N &= \left( \frac{a}{2 x} \right) W \\
\end{aligned} $$

As you can see the scale measurement $N \ge W$ since $x \leq \tfrac{a}{2}$. On when the pivot is in the middle then $N=W$.

But if you had a handle you can pull horizontally only then you have a situation as follows where the  pivot force equals the weight

[image: fig2]

The amount of force needed to pull is

$$F = \left( \frac{a}{2 b} - \frac{x}{b} \right) W$$

and again, this force becomes zero when the pivot is at the center $x=a/2$.

Comment: That's a great answer. So you are saying the scale is measuring *at least* the weight of the object, if not more. Never less. That's actually good for my case (I want to overly safe).

Comment: One question though, why is (a/2)F−(a/2−x)N=0 ? (I feel like I missed a step). Do note that while I had a Physics course during my university study, it was +25 years ago.

Comment: As long as you are pushing down with your hand the scale is going to read more. The condition for this is $x<a/2$. NOTE that $(a/2)$ is the distance $F$ is applied from the pivot, and $(a/2-x)$ is the distance $N$ is applied from the pivot. It is a balance of torques here.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a second balance and add the two readings.

Another method using two "knife edges$, pieces of wood/plastic with a triangular cross section.

Set up the apparatus as below making sure that the knife edges are parallel to one another and an edge of the object.

[image]

$M$ is the unknown mass of the object, $R$ is the reading on the scale, $X$ is the unknown distance of the centre of mass of the object from the knife edge on the scale and $x$ is the measured distance between knife edges.

Taking moments about the right hand knife edge, $R\,X = (x-X)M$.

Thus you have an equation with two unknowns $X$ and $M$ and taking another two readings, $x$ and $R$, after moving the position of the right hand knife edge will give you a second equation and enable you to fine $M$ (and $X$).

Taking a number of readings and drawing a graph of $R$ against $1/x$ might give you a more accurate value of $M$ (negative intercept on $R$ axis) and indicate the error in $M$ from the scatter of the data points.

$R\,X = (x-X)M\Rightarrow R=(XM)\,\dfrac 1 x -M$

which is the form of the general equation of a starlight line $y = m\,x +c$ with gradient $m=XM$ and intercept on $R$ axis of $c=-M$.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Scale diagram]

You would be applying just enough force on the tip of the object to balance it out by yourself. This force you applied causes a counter torque to be applied on the object, this counter torque cancels the torque applied by the **unbalanced mass** seen in the above diagram as scanned with red color. So the mass measured by the scale would be full mass minus unbalanced mass.

**Note:** This is just an attempt made by me, it may not be accurate or correct.

Comment: I do not know about the theory, but I just tested with two bathroom scales without holding with my hands and the result match the original sample with a 3% error. So, I do not know your math is correct.

Comment: @rufo it's good to make experiments and collecting data. So, apparently my calculations were incorrect and I wasn't so sure about them. Are you able to confirm the mass you've measured with dome sort of verified data like in the product web page? Did the both scales show the same mass? How did you place the scales under the object? I'm a bit curious about that.